# Display list of object's child arrays containing dupes with 1 bullet per index using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

I have an object (`searchedMenu`) containing 3 arrays of equal lengths (`name`, `short_name`, and `description`).

```
for(var i=0;i<description.length;i++){
    searchedMenu.name[i] = description[i].name;
    searchedMenu.short_name[i] = description[i].short_name;
    searchedMenu.description[i] = description[i].description;
} 
menu.searchedMenu = searchedMenu;
```

I want to display each `name`, `short_name`, and `description` as an unordered list item like this:

- name1, short_name1, description1
- name2, short_name2, description2

I'm struggling to do this. I've declared my controller in the relevant `div` as

```
<div class="container" ng-controller = "NarrowItDownController as narrow">
```

If I do this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in narrow.searchedMenu"> {{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

I get 3 bullet points containing all elements of each array like this:

- name1, name2,...
- short_name1, short_name2, ...
- description1, description2, ...

If I do this:

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in narrow.searchedMenu"> {{item.name}}, {{item.short_name}}, {{item.description}}</li>
```

I get:

- , ,
- , ,
- , ,

As an experiment I also tried this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in narrow.searchedMenu.name"> {{item}}</li>
```

and it gave me nothing in the browser with a console error of:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=item%20in%20narrow.searchedMenu.name&p1=string%3AOrange%20Chicken&p2=Orange%20Chicken

The `console.log("Searched menu: ", menu.searchedMenu);` is:

```
Searched menu:  Object {name: Array[219], short_name: Array[219], description: Array[219]}
```

The full controller code is (this is a dirty work in progress):

```
NarrowItDownController.$inject = ['MenuSearchService'];
function NarrowItDownController(MenuSearchService) {
  var menu = this;

  var promise = MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems();
  var item_name = ["",""];
  var description;

  var searchValue = "ton";
  function containsFilter(value) {
    return value.indexOf(searchValue) !== -1;
  }

  promise.then(function (response) {
    menu.results = response.data;
    menu.results = menu.results.menu_items;

    description = response.data;
    description = description.menu_items;
    console.log(description);

    var searchedMenu = {};
    searchedMenu.name = [];
    searchedMenu.short_name = [];
    searchedMenu.description = [];

    for(var i=0;i<description.length;i++){
        searchedMenu.name[i] = description[i].name;
        searchedMenu.short_name[i] = description[i].short_name;
        searchedMenu.description[i] = description[i].description;
    }

    console.log(searchedMenu);
    menu.searchedMenu = searchedMenu;//description.filter(containsFilter);
    console.log("Searched menu: ", menu.searchedMenu);

  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Something went terribly wrong.");
  });

  menu.logMenuItems = function (searchTerm) {
    var promise = MenuSearchService.getMatchedMenuItems(searchTerm);

    promise.then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
  };

}
```

Note that I hard coded the search term in the example above because it's a work in progress.

Comment: where is your angular controller code?

Comment: also maybe show us the console.log of narrow.searchedMenu

Comment: @FerasSalim The first code block is the key part of the Controller code but I can add more of the code, no problem. Just give me 10 seconds.

Comment: @defaultcheckbox Sure it says `Object {name: Array[219], short_name: Array[219], description: Array[219]}`

Comment: Why do you need to transform the `description` array in 3 arrays. You could use `ng-repeat="item in description"` and bind with `item.name`, `item.short_name` and `item.description`

Comment: @Troopers That's a good idea, but I tried it and couldn't get it to work. Maybe if we solve this then doing that will work as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in narrow.searchedMenu.name track by $index"> {{ item }}, {{ narrow.searchedMenu.short_name[$index] }}, {{ narrow.searchedMenu.description[$index] }}</li>
</ul>
```

The `searchedMenu` object contains three arrays, therefore you can loop through one of the arrays and in each step of the loop, extract the elements from the other arrays with the `$index`.

AngularJS does not allow duplicates in a ng-repeat directive therefore you must add `track by $index` to your repeater

Comment: It worked!!!! :-) Thank you, that's super awesome. I never knew about `track by`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to split it out, you should just do this

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in description"> {{item.name}}, {{item.shortName}},{{item.description}},</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That doesn't result in anything being displayed in my browser

Comment: What is your data structure? Could you give an example

Comment: Sure, so the object has those 3 arrays you have in your answer. If you want to see the raw data it's here: https://davids-restaurant.herokuapp.com/menu_items.json

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
menu.searchedMenu = description;
```

In your template:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in searchedMenu"> {{item.name}}, {{item.shortName}},{{item.description}},</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That looks good in the console but nothing is coming up in the browser. Maybe because of the controller as syntax (i.e. `narrow`?)

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think that for isla not necesary because the key values is the same in both part data and the menú so i recomend that only do the last part, that is menu.searchedMenu = searchedMenu; and change the searchedmenu in the right to your description and second ir the left part is inside of a controller change menú to this variable and in the ng repeat put:

`<li ng-repeat="item in searchedMenu"> {{item.name}}, {{item.short_name}}, {{item.description}}</li>`

It should work